# « Rencontres éclair » ou « Rencontres éclairs »

Tags: accord

J’ai un doute, il faut dire :

> Rencontres éclair (sans S à éclair)

ou

> Rencontres éclairs (avec un S à éclair) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'accord se fait pour certains, pas pour d'autres, tout est question d'interprétation.

Pour ceux qui considèrent que *éclair* est dans ce cas un substantif employé de façon métaphorique il n'y a pas d'accord :

> Éclair est invariable dans de nombreuses expressions : des "voyages éclair", "des visites éclair", "des jeux éclair", "des victoires éclair", etc. On écrit : "par éclairs" (par instants). [Cordial](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/%C3%A9clair-adjectif.php)

Ceux qui considèrent que *éclair* est un adjectif font l'accord. Dans son article sur les mots composés (car on trouve aussi la forme NOM-éclair) [Orthonet](http://orthonet.sdv.fr/pages/informations_p8.html) écrit :

> Rare dans le passé, le type *mot-clé, loi-cadre*... est devenu envahissant. Un nombre croissant de noms, placés en apposition après un autre nom, prennent une fonction d’épithète, jadis réservée aux adjectifs :"une guerre-éclair, des images-choc(s), une ville-lumière, des ventes record, des livres phares...(trait d'union irrégulier, mais fréquent).
> [...]
> Quand le second terme joue un rôle d’épithète par rapport au premier, et exprime une qualité de cet objet ou de cette personne, il est normal qu’il le suive dans un emploi au pluriel : « des *mots-clés*, des *visites-éclairs*. Mais quand il a une fonction de complément du premier, par ellipse d’une préposition : *des chaussures-sport* (= de sport), le pluriel n’est pas un « accord », mais un choix de sens.

Ce que reprend la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4531) de l'Office québécois de la langue française :

> Le nom *éclair* est souvent employé juxtaposé à un autre nom pour qualifier quelque chose de très rapide, d’éphémère ou de soudain. Les ouvrages ne s’entendent pas sur le pluriel d’*éclair*. La plupart conseillent de ne pas l’accorder en nombre, considérant ainsi qu’éclair demeure un nom. La structure nom + *éclair* est alors interprétée comme une construction réduite dans laquelle *éclair* signifie « aussi bref et soudain que l’éclair ». D’autres ouvrages, par contre, attribuent à *éclair* un statut d’adjectif et acceptent ainsi qu’il varie en nombre. Ainsi, aucune des deux graphies, avec *-s* ou sans *-s*, ne peut actuellement être tenue pour fautive.

Personnellement ce qui me gêne dans cet accord adjectival c'est qu'il porte uniquement sur l'accord du pluriel, car bien sûr il n'est jamais question de faire l'accord avec le féminin :

> – Le premier ministre a l’habitude des visites éclairs dans différentes circonscriptions. (BDL)
>
> – des visites-éclairs (Orthonet)

Answer (score 3):

Faute de règle précise... Les deux se disent. Même si la majorité des linguistes tend à ne pas faire l'accord.